# Writing the hexadecimal indication '\x' only, while avoiding “ValueError: invalid \x escape”

Tags: python, python-3.x

There are a lot of posts about the error message `ValueError: invalid \x escape`, however, I am still stuck, although it's a simple problem. I am trying to build a bytestring line out of different building blocks. In the end it has to look like:

```
b'Kh\x10\x10\x10'
```

so two ascii symbols at the beginning and three hexadecimal values. I already have the `K` (from `dict_birdnumbers[int(birdname)]`) and the `'10'` (`finangle`) as variables. I tried it with a raw literal string

```
hex = r'\x'
line3 =  dict_birdnumbers[int(birdname)] + 'h' + hex + finangle + hex + finangle + hex + finangle
print(line3.encode())
```

I use the `.encode()` to ensure that it's a bytestring. However, the result I get is

```
b'Kh\\x10\\x10\\x10'
```

so one backslash too much. If I delete the backslash in `hex` I only get `b'Khx10x10x10'` . If I use a normal string like `hex = '\x'` I get the error message `ValueError: invalid \x escape`. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\xhh` is a *notation*; each `\xhh` sequence creates **one** character. You can't concatenate `\x` and two hex digits to get the same effect.

Instead, just pass a sequence of integers to `bytes()`:

```
finagle = int(finangle, 16)  # assuming finagle is a hex notation string
line3 =  b'%sh%s' % (
    dict_birdnumbers[int(birdname)].encode('ascii'),
    bytes([finangle, finangle, finangle])
)
```

This creates a `bytes` object with 3 bytes, each with integer value 16, hex value 10. The `repr()` output of `bytes` happens to use `\xhh` to display such bytes because the alternative is not really printable (this is done for all non-printable byte values, those outside of the printable ASCII range):

```
>>> bytes([0x10, 0x10, 0x10])  # 3 integers using hex syntax
b'\x10\x10\x10'
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!